# Tags Disappeared from Profile

Tags: support, user-profile

I was a stackoverflow user, and found this wonderful gaming site as a result.  On SO, my account was an OpenID through my gmail address.  When I made an account here, I was dumb and forgot that and made a normal account through my alias email (which has an alias name), which I tend to use for gaming purposes.  I didn't think anything of it until it recently combined the two accounts automatically, which changed my name and re-awarded all my badges and Diablo III contest gems.  I got rid of the alternate login through "my logins," and changed my name back, and I think I'm back to where I want to be.  However, it says that I haven't participated in any tags.  Did the database get all screwy when the accounts combined, or should I have taken different steps to un-link the accounts?

Edit: I posted this without having participated in any tags since the merge.  Since then, I have answered a few more questions, and my tags still aren't showing up.

Comment: That is pretty weird. I would bet it's not anything you did wrong

Comment: My tags are back. Database lag?

Comment: @Ben Yeah, most likely. As with most things, when in doubt, blame caching but if things don't fix themselves in a day or so give us a shout. :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the correct procedure when account merging is going haywire is to contact the team, at team+gaming@stackexchange.com.